# mmap:Operation not supported

Tags: mmap

I am using mmap on Optane PM, however, something wrong occurs:terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'   what():  Cannot mmap | Operation not supported

Does anybody know how to use mmap successfully?